# OpenGL Draw Trouble

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I made a loader for opengl which reads the vertex , vertex normal and all that sort of stuff into vertices all in order . The loader is right i have checked all the values and it is what it should be. For some reason i still cant actually get anything up on the screen.

```
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include "Loader.h"

#define SC_WIDTH 600
#define SC_HEIGHT 600
#define REFRESH_RATE 0.03f

loader load;

int main()
{
    // Create the main window
     sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(SC_WIDTH, SC_HEIGHT, 32), "SFML OpenGL");

    // Create a clock for measuring time elapsed
    sf::Clock clock;

    //load file
    load.openFile();

    // Set color and depth clear value
    glClearDepth(1.f);
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

    // Enable Z-buffer read and write
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);


    //lighing
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,&load.totalVertices);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,&load.faceNormal);

     // Setup a perspective projection
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90.f, 1.f, 1.f, 500.f);

    // Start game loop
    while (App.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event Event;
        while (App.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            // Close window : exit
            if (Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.close();

            // Escape key : exit
            if ((Event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape))
                App.close();

            // Resize event : adjust viewport
            if (Event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
               glViewport(0, 0, Event.size.width, Event.size.height);
        }

        // Set the active window before using OpenGL commands
        // It's useless here because active window is always the same,
        // but don't forget it if you use multiple windows or controls
        App.setActive();


        if((float)clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds()>REFRESH_RATE){
            // Clear colour and depth buffer
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glPopMatrix();
            glTranslatef(0.f,0.f,-10.f);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,(GLsizei)(load.totalVertices.size()/3));
            glPushMatrix();

            clock.restart();
        }


        // Finally, display rendered frame on screen
        App.display();
    }

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to call `glOrtho` by any chance?

Comment: what is glOrtho looked online but doesn't seem to explain.

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml pretty much set up your coordinate system.

Comment: But i'm using gluPerspective(90.f, 1.f, 1.f, 500.f); wouldn't that have been sorted in this call ? Would it be glfutsum

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you are dividing the number of vertices by 3 in your call to `glDrawArrays (...)`, which leads me to believe you think that parameter is the number of triangles (or more generally, the number of primitives). It is not, it is the number of vertices. You should not be dividing by 3.

The other thing to note is that you are calling `glPopMatrix (...)` and `glPushMatrix (...)` in the wrong order. You basically underflow the matrix stack the first time you try to draw anything. You *could* swap the two calls and fix this problem, but in all honesty they are not necessary in the first place because you have loaded an identity matrix before calling `glTranslatef (...)`.

Comment: I updated the code got rid of the /3 and also tried moving the push and pop around and taking them out. Still had no joy

Comment: @user3052480: Then your problem must lie somewhere else. Those are the only issues immediately noticeable in the code you presented. I suspect either your function to load the vertices is incorrect or your camera is oriented improperly.

Comment: It must be the camera orientation the vertex's are right , i have checked them a lot. How could i orient camera properly >

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. It is very difficult to answer that sort of question without knowing the range of values in your vertices. One thing you could do is find the minimum and maximum X, Y and Z vertex values and then divide each vertex's X, Y and Z values so that the vertices are all in the range [-1,1]. If you use identity modelview and projection matrices then every one of those points is guaranteed to be visible (you will be drawing into a special coordinate space known as Normalized Device Coordinates). It is not usually a useful coordinate space, but handy for debugging.